# installing SVN - CentOS - cannot find -lexpat

Tags: centos, svn

Hey guys, I'm trying to install SVN on CentOS 5. Unfortunately a simple yum install isn't going to work (afaik) because I'm using the DirectAdmin control panel.

When it comes to running 'make' I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lexpat
```

I'm new to installing things without yum (!) so am a bit lost. Do you have any advice on how to get past this hurdle?

Just to give a little more context to the error;

```
/apache   -I/usr/include/apache -I/etc/svn-install/subversion-1.6.2/sqlite-amalgamation  -o subversion/svn/util.o -c subversion/svn/util.c
cd subversion/svn && /bin/sh /etc/svn-install/subversion-1.6.2/libtool --tag=CC --silent --mode=link gcc  -g -O2  -g -O2 -pthread   -rpath /usr/lib -o svn  add-cmd.o blame-cmd.o cat-cmd.o changelist-cmd.o checkout-cmd.o cleanup-cmd.o commit-cmd.o conflict-callbacks.o copy-cmd.o delete-cmd.o diff-cmd.o export-cmd.o help-cmd.o import-cmd.o info-cmd.o list-cmd.o lock-cmd.o log-cmd.o main.o merge-cmd.o mergeinfo-cmd.o mkdir-cmd.o move-cmd.o notify.o propdel-cmd.o propedit-cmd.o propget-cmd.o proplist-cmd.o props.o propset-cmd.o resolve-cmd.o resolved-cmd.o revert-cmd.o status-cmd.o status.o switch-cmd.o tree-conflicts.o unlock-cmd.o update-cmd.o util.o ../../subversion/libsvn_client/libsvn_client-1.la ../../subversion/libsvn_wc/libsvn_wc-1.la ../../subversion/libsvn_ra/libsvn_ra-1.la ../../subversion/libsvn_delta/libsvn_delta-1.la ../../subversion/libsvn_diff/libsvn_diff-1.la ../../subversion/libsvn_subr/libsvn_subr-1.la /etc/httpd/lib/libaprutil-1.la  -lexpat /etc/httpd/lib/libapr-1.la -luuid -lrt -lcrypt  -lpthread -ldl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lexpat
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [subversion/svn/svn] Error 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the expat development package

Try

```
yum install expat-devel
```

and rerun make after that

though I doubt this question belongs on SF

Comment: sorry :( is there another stack overflow / serverfault-type website it would be better on?

Comment: Don't worry about it too much ;-)
Did you manage to compile it yet?

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest going to the official Subversion site (http://subversion.tigris.org/project_packages.html).  There you get a link to collabNet BINARY packages for Redhat versions 4,5 and others.

Since CentOS is really a recompilation of Redhat AS sources you should have no problem using the RedHat binary packages.  Its also nice as all the necessary binaries, modules and such are included.